# Why can't I import attribute values?

Tags: magento2, attributes, import

I've created a new **attribute** - **GTIN**.

All I want to do is **import** my **barcodes** into the **GTIN** field **per SKU**.

```
sku,additional_attributes

AM0005930-34,gtin=08033546253915
```

I've created the above **.csv**, but the import says all my rows are incorrect.

Can I not import my barcodes this way?
**My attribute** is a **text field**.

Surely Magento 2 can support this?

Comment: You check your CSV settings?  You try it enclosed?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of top 5 records with header of your CSV?